# Get user input in wicket DateTimeField

Tags: java, wicket

I'm trying to get the user-selected value of a DateTimeField, but am failing. I currently have the following code, which works perfectly for my DropDownChoice objects:

```
public class DateTimeFieldPanel extends Panel {

    private final Date date;
    private String value;

    public DateTimeFieldPanel(Date date) {
        super("component");
        this.date = date;

        final DateTimeField dateTimeField = new DateTimeField("dateTimeField", new PropertyModel<Date>(this, "date"));

        dateTimeField.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {

            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                value = dateTimeField.getModel().getObject().toString();
            }
        });

        add(dateTimeField);
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the model does not have an object for some reason, so getObject() returns null. 
What am I doing wrong? Why does this work for DropDownChoicePanel but not for DateTimeField?

Many thanks!

Update:
I now have this mess:

```
dateTimeField = new DateTimeField("dateTimeField", new PropertyModel<Date>(this, "date")) {

        @Override
        protected DateTextField newDateTextField(String id, PropertyModel dateFieldModel) {
            final DateTextField dateField = super.newDateTextField(id, dateFieldModel);
            dateField.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("change") {

                @Override
                protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    processInput();
                }
            });
            return dateField;

        }

        @Override
        protected TextField<Integer> newHoursTextField(final String id, IModel<Integer> model, Class<Integer> type) {
            final TextField<Integer> hoursTextField = new TextField<Integer>(id, model, type);
            hoursTextField.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("change") {

                @Override
                protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    processInput();
                }
            });

            hoursTextField.add(getMaximumHours() == 24 ? RangeValidator.range(0, 23) : RangeValidator.range(1, 12));
            hoursTextField.setLabel(new Model<String>(HOURS));
            return hoursTextField;
        }

        private int getMaximumHours() {
            return getMaximumHours(use12HourFormat());
        }

        private int getMaximumHours(boolean use12HourFormat) {
            return use12HourFormat ? 12 : 24;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean use12HourFormat() {
            String pattern = DateTimeFormat.patternForStyle("-S", getLocale());
            return pattern.indexOf('a') != -1 || pattern.indexOf('h') != -1 || pattern.indexOf('K') != -1;
        }
    };
```

Basically I figured out that the DateTimeField consists of three TextFields, one for the date, hour and minutes. I have to add the ajax behaviour to these fields seperately by overriding the methods that create them, and then call processInput() so that the ModelObject for the DateTimeField is updated. This works for the date part. For the hours, I can override the method that creates the field, but calling processInput() doesn't seem to update the ModelObject for my DateTimeField. Finally, my biggest problem is that there is no method that creates a field for the minutes. Therefore I cannot override it in the first place. 
I suspect I'm making this way too complicated, but where am I going wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why the documentation would point you to an `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior`.

The problem here is that it will only update the content of each field if that changes. So if the minutes field changes it will only POST the minuteField input. Therefore everytime you try to convert the input after doing a minute/hour update it will not find a date and therefore fail.

See DateTimeField.convertInput

```
            // Get the converted input values
        Date dateFieldInput = dateField.getConvertedInput();
        Integer hoursInput = hoursField.getConvertedInput();
        Integer minutesInput = minutesField.getConvertedInput();
        AM_PM amOrPmInput = amOrPmChoice.getConvertedInput();

        if (dateFieldInput == null)
        {
            return;
        }
```

I would recommend wrapping the DateTimeField in a Form and just submitting the whole form during the change event, like:

```
    final Form<?> form = new Form("form");
    add(form);

    IModel<Date> dateModel = Model.of();
    DateTimeField dateTimeField = new DateTimeField("dateTimeField", dateModel) {

        @Override
        protected DateTextField newDateTextField(String id, PropertyModel dateFieldModel) {
            DateTextField dateField = super.newDateTextField(id, dateFieldModel);
            dateField.add(new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior(form, "change") {
            });
            return dateField;

        }

        @Override
        protected TextField<Integer> newMinutesTextField(String id, IModel<Integer> model, Class<Integer> type) {
            TextField<Integer> textField = super.newMinutesTextField(id, model, type);
            textField.add(new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior(form, "change") {
            });

            return textField;
        }

        @Override
        protected TextField<Integer> newHoursTextField(final String id, IModel<Integer> model, Class<Integer> type) {
            TextField<Integer> textField = super.newHoursTextField(id, model, type);
            textField.add(new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior(form, "change") {
            });
            return textField;
        }
    };
    form.add(dateTimeField);
```

This will actually submit all three values instead of only one. And everything should work.

Comment: Hi Thorsten, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I'm left with 2 questions though. 
Most importantly: as stated before, the method newMinutesTextField() does not exist and thus cannot be overridden.
Secondly (but not as important): this solution still seems to submit all values seperately. Each time after updating one of the fields (date, hours or minutes), the form submit is triggered. So when I start entering a date and move on to enter the hours, the date is already submitted. This however is something I can code around so it's not a big problem.

Comment: Apologies, I just figured out I overlooked the part where you check for nullvalues. However the biggest problem still remains. Also I'm unsure of the benefit of adding everything to a form, as I could have checked for null values even if the DateTimeField was not part of a form.

Comment: The main reason that I added the Form was so I would just submit those 3 values (date, hours, minutes) - you might have a larger form around this and don't want everything to be submitted (or you want that). You'll need one Form around the FormComponent anyway. Which Wicket version are you using? I tested the code with the lastest wicket 7.x version and I had the newMinutesTextField() method

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the version. My wicket-core version was up to date, however I had stupidly omitted the version for wicket-datetime, and apparently I ended up with an outdated version. Problem solved! As for the form, my field is already part of a form (together with other fields)so I think I will stick to using the AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior. 
Many thanks!

Comment: Does that really help you? I would assume with the AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior you're ending up in the original problems (on update of hours/minutes no date)? Wicket actually specificly supports nested forms ... so there is no real harm in using them